# Question about determinants 2

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I understand the first part, but I'm a bit confused on how to go about the second part. I get to

$$t_1^2-\operatorname{Tr}(A)t_1=t_2^2-\operatorname{Tr}(A)t_2=-\det(A)$$

but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: When does a degree $2$ polynomial have two distinct real roots?

Comment: Hint: Think about the discriminant.

Comment: when $t_1$ and $t_2$ are equal obviously but is there another case I'm missing?

Comment: No, you misunderstood the second part: what's really asked is whether there exists two numbers such that $\det(A-tI)=0$.

Comment: My gut is telling  me that there probably is. For det(A) to equal zero, ad=bc so ad-bc is equal to zero right?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a question of when a quadratic equation has two distince real solutions.

If the coefficients $a,b,c$ are real and $a\ne0$, then the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots if and only if $b^2-4ac>0$.

In this case you have $a=1$, $b=-\operatorname{Tr}(A)$, and $c=\det A$.

Comment: okay so I plugged in the components of A and got 

$a^2$+2ad+$d^2$-4ad+4bc>0 

where do I go from here?

Comment: What you get should be $(\operatorname{Tr}(A))^2-4\det(A)$. That is $(a-d)^2+4bc$. That is the same as what you say you got.  If that's positive, then the equation has two distinct real solutions. Notice that $(a-d)^2$ can only be $\ge0$, so $(a-d)^2$ would have to be outweighed by a negative value of $4bc$ that has a large enough absolute value. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: BTW, when typing $a^2+2ad+d^2-4ad+4bc>0$, just put the whole thing between a single pair of dollar signs.  That way the fonts match, you get proper spacing, and your minus sign doesn't look like a stubby little hyphen. That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$